# microcontroller slew rate

Tags: microcontroller

I have to control some device which require minimum 40mV/uS as slew rate for ENABLE input. My mcu runs at 3.3V so the rise and fall should be faster than 82.5uS. This is correct? Does it matter the actual speed of MCU?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's correct.  If you're comparing to datasheet rise time maybe it would be slightly better to use 2.6V for the calculation, as the rise times are spec'd at 10% - 90% voltage instead of the full 3.3V swing.

But it hardly matters here.  Any microcontroller should have faster edges than that.  You normally would only get in trouble with slowly rising lines, e.g. an RC delay circuit, or open-collector outputs, or if the enable input is shared with a lot of capacitance for some reason.  A microcontroller with its push-pull outputs should give a really nice signal.